# inserting a lot of data via create_bulk

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-queryset

hello I have a table named Exercise data where I pass data from form and save them in the db, my problem is that I have more same objects to save inside the db but I don't know how to do it.
I left you my views.py file where you can find the code I created.
I read around that I should use the create_bulk but I don't understand how I can pass it some data from my form, could someone help me please? =)

views.py

```
@login_required
def creaScheda(request):
 if request.method == "POST":
  form = CreaSchedaForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
   schedaName = form.cleaned_data['nome_scheda']
   scheda = form.save(commit = False)
   scheda.utente = request.user
   scheda.save()

   gruppi = DatiGruppi(
    giorni_settimana = form.cleaned_data['giorni_settimana'],
    dati_gruppo = form.cleaned_data['dati_gruppo'],
    gruppi_scheda = Schede.objects.get(nome_scheda = schedaName)
   )
   gruppi.save()

   esercizi = DatiEsercizi(
    serie = form.cleaned_data['serie'],
    ripetizione = form.cleaned_data['ripetizione'],
    peso = form.cleaned_data['peso'],
    gruppo_single = DatiGruppi.objects.get(gruppi_scheda = scheda.id),
    dati_esercizio = form.cleaned_data['dati_esercizio']
   )
   #esercizi.save()
   print(esercizi)

   return redirect('/backoffice')

else:
 form = CreaSchedaForm()
```

context = {"form": form}
return render(request, "crea_scheda.html", context)

Comment: Those are 3 different models. Bulk create is for creating the same objects. Can you show the part where `I have more same objects to save inside the db `?

Comment: the model named exercises is what I would like to be able to publish